# How come all ConcurrentMap (key, value) pairs are stored in memory?

Tags: jvm, guava, concurrenthashmap

I was reading [this article](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) about Guava cache, which states:

> A Cache is similar to ConcurrentMap, but not quite the same. The most
>   fundamental difference is that a ConcurrentMap persists all elements
>   that are added to it until they are explicitly removed.

How can one know that ConcurrentMap elements are always stored in memory? Surely, if the JVM memory limit is reached they will be evicted?

What does ConcurrentMap do to ensure the JVM keeps its elements in memory?

I was looking over the Guava ConcurrentMap implementation but I still didn't understand.

Comment: *Surely, if the JVM memory limit is reached they will be evicted?*: no. An OutOfMemoryError will be thrown. *What does ConcurrentMap do to ensure the JVM keeps its elements in memory?*: well, there is nothing to ensure. It stores them in memory, so they are in memory. If you wonder if the OS can swap this memory to the disk, yes, it can, and the map doesn't do anything to prevent that. "memory" here doesn't mean "physical memory".

Comment: @JBNizet actually, the cited statement doesn’t even use the word “memory”. It says that all elements in a `ConcurrentMap` *persist*, regardless of the media used. The only flaw in this statement is that it seems to confuse the interface `ConcurrentMap` with the particular implementation `ConcurrentHashMap`.